# How to new WeakMap with array as parameter?

Tags: javascript, weakmap

I have been reading MDN docs about WeakMap.
And it mentions the syntax:

`new WeakMap([iterable])`

But when I tried this, error occurred:

```
var arr = [{a:1}];
var wm1 = new WeakMap(arr);
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Invalid value used as weak map key

Could you please offer me an example about how to do it via an array?

Comment: The weakmap constructor takes an iterable of *key-value pairs*, i.e. two-element arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation says:

> Iterable is an Array or other iterable object whose elements are key-value pairs (2-element Arrays).

`{a: 1}` is an object, not a 2-element array.

Further down it says:

> Keys of WeakMaps are of the type Object only.

So you can't use a string as a key in a `WeakMap`.

Try:

```js
var obj = {a:1};
var arr = [[obj, 1]];
var wm1 = new WeakMap(arr);
console.log(wm1.has(obj));
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a 2D array, like `[[key1, value1], [key2, value2]]`. As you don't have keys a WeakSet would be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap)

> Iterable is an Array or other iterable object whose elements are
>   key-value pairs (2-element Arrays).

And

> The keys must be objects and the values can be arbitrary values.

So:

```
var o = {a:1};
var arr = [[o, 10]];
var wm1 = new WeakMap(arr);
```